# LINQ Query, Return Max Value with Where Clause

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on an API; how can I set my linq query up to return the max value with a where condition?

See the example code below; I can return the max value of the field I want, but I need to filter it where another column value equals something.

```
var lot = db.ShrinkLotData.Where(x => x.SupplierMfgLot.ToLower() == label.SupplierMfgLot.ToLower() && x.CatPattern.ToLower() == label.CatPattern.ToLower())
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    if (lot.Result == null)
    {
        var lots = db.ShrinkLotData.Where(x => x.CatPattern.ToLower() == label.CatPattern.ToLower());

        int internallot = db.ShrinkLotData.Max(x => x.InternalLotNum).Value;

        return Ok(lot);
    }

    return Ok(lot);
}
```

for the internallot, I want to return the highest value using similar syntax as the lots syntax.. (Where the catpattern equals a specific value)

What am I overlooking?

Thanks!

Comment: `db.ShrinkLotData.Where(....).Max(....)` that's what you need to do.

Comment: You can *chain* LINQ methods! Didn't you know that? That's the philosophy of LINQ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you basically need to use `Where` and `Max` together, so that you can select max value with a where condition.

```
db.ShrinkLotData.Where(x => x.CatPattern.ToLower() == label.CatPattern.ToLower()).Max(x => x.InternalLotNum).Value;
```

More Info : [Composability of Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq#composability-of-queries):

> ..., you compose them in method syntax by
>   chaining the method calls together. This is what the compiler does
>   behind the scenes when you write queries by using query syntax. And
>   because a query variable does not store the results of the query, you
>   can modify it or use it as the basis for a new query at any time, even
>   after it has been executed.